# Filter query to match a via ring only on a specific layer

Tags: pcb, altium, design-rules

I'm working on a 4-layer PCB which uses 210µm copper internally and 70µm copper on the outer layers. Also I only use Thru (1:4) and remove unused via pads with`tools -> remove unused pad shapes` tool. Also those via's are plated.

I'm looking for a way to design a clearance rule which enforces .5mm clearance from the the annular ring of a via on a mid layer to a hole (*purple arrow*).

I've tried the following query:

- Object 1: `OnMid`
- Object 2: `Hole`

Object 1 only matches the trace's on the mid layers but not the annular rings they are connencted to. They are matched by `OnMultiLayer`, however then the annular rings on `Top` and `Bottom` are also matched, what is not desired. I need a mid-layer specific query because the clearance constraint on the outside layers are not as strict.

Are there any ideas on how to match a MultiLayerObject only on a specific layer?

Thank you for your ideas,
Alex

[image: 3d view]

Comment: What have the many altium user sites come up with on this?